# Don't lose data when restarting the app?

Tags: android

I have an activity which changes the language of the app using `set.Locale`. Is it possible to maintain the language when restarting the app ?

Comment: yes, store it in SharePreferences

Answer (score 2):

Save the data in a persistent storage. Like `SharedPreferences`. Then you can restore the data from it when you restart the app.

Refer the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html